# Apache Commons CSV : Read Values with comma

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am converting CSV files to a Java Bean. I need to maintain the comma inside a value which is enclosed in **""**.

Here is my code.

```
public static PPRCV convertContestToObj(String fileName) throws IOException {

    PPRCV pprcvHandler = PPRCVFactory.getPPRCVTable(fileName);

    CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.newFormat(',').withEscape('"');

    List<PPRCV> pprcvs = new ArrayList<>();
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

    CSVParser csvFileParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFileFormat);

    List<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvFileParser.getRecords();

    for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvRecords) {
        pprcvs.add(pprcvHandler.populateDynamicDetails(csvRecord));
    }

    return pprcvHandler;

}
```

Sample CSV line:

**7080001, XI, ProvinceX, TownX, BRGX, "SHOOL, BRGX", "0054A,0055A,0055B,0055C"**

my DTO

```
private String precintCode;

private String regionName;

private String provinceName;

private String municipalityName;

private String districtName;

private String votingCenter;

private String precint;
```

My expected output should be

> precintCode = "7080001"
>
> regionName = "XI"
>
> provinceName = "ProvinceX"
>
> municipalityName = "TownX"
>
> districtName = "BRGX"
>
> votingCenter = "SCHOOL, BRGX"
>
> precint = "0054A,0055A,0055B,0055C"

**However actual output is this**

> precintCode = "7080001"
>
> regionName = "XI"
>
> provinceName = "ProvinceX"
>
> municipalityName = "TownX"
>
> districtName = "BRGX"
>
> votingCenter = ""SCHOOL"
>
> precint = " , BRGX,"0054A"

Comment: did you consider switching implementation to OpenCSV? It has richer API in comparison to CSV support from Apache Commons
http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it using the **withQuote** function from the library.

```
CSVFormat.EXCEL.newFormat(',').withQuote('"')
```

Comment: At least on commons-csv 1,5, newFormat() is static, so your example is effectively the same as `CSVFormat.newFormat(',').withQuote('"')`

Answer (score 4):

You need the `withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces()` optione here. All other settings could be remain `DEFAULT`.

```
    final Reader in = new StringReader("7080001, XI, ProvinceX, TownX, BRGX, \"SHOOL, BRGX\", \"0054A,0055A,0055B,0055C\" ");
    final CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces();

    for (CSVRecord record: csvFileFormat.parse(in)) {
        for (String field: record) {
            System.out.println("\"" + field + "\"");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

The output is

```
"7080001"
"XI"
"ProvinceX"
"TownX"
"BRGX"
"SHOOL, BRGX"
"0054A,0055A,0055B,0055C"
```

Comment: I require the similar thing .. But If I am using it I am getting error     
        invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter                                   which goes away if I use WithQuote(null) .. But then it is taking comma within quotes to read the value

Comment: I'm impressed how no sense this method naming is and how smooth it works

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried using the [`CSVFormat.DEFAULT` constant](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/archives/1.2/apidocs/index.html)?-- it's for CSV files adhering to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

Answer (score 0):

The following way worked for me:

`CSVFormat.EXCEL.withQuote('"')`