# CSV - Count #Columns

Tags: java, csv

At start I count number of comma, like:

```
stream.forEach(csvLine -> {
    int commaCounter = countMatches(csvLine, ",");
    if (commaCounter != FIELDS_IN_CSV - 1) {
        // Alert
    }
```

but I found (thank you bug) that comma is a legal character when it surround by apostrophes, like `"This is one, value"`.

I look for a short way to solve it but found nothing (using openCsv library, if it's help).

of course, I can iterate, enqueue/dequeue the apostrophes* to a stack and count the separate comma.
does here a short way to do it?

- or increase / decrease apostrophes counter value

Comment: What is the structure of your .csv?

Comment: @Andrey, not sure I understand you, regular csv like a,b,c,d but also can be a,b,"c,2",d

Comment: @AsfK, each line within the CSV could have a different comma count? Is that why you check the count over all lines?

Comment: @munyul the Arch. requirement is to verify each row in the csv has 35 fields, when "a,b" if equal to one field...

Comment: you can try to read your .csv using Appache Commons CSV, it can be set to ignore escaped comma, see here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36129598/apache-commons-csv-read-values-with-comma

Comment: An open implementation such as openCSV surely handles this!? If you can't easily find the answer you're looking for there, then create your own "checker", the code is quite simple. Convert the string to a char array and then count the comma not within a pair of quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple *do it yourself* solution would be:

```
int getFieldCount( String csvLine )
{
    char[] ch = csvLine.toCharArray();
    int len = ch.length, pos = 0, commaCounter = 0;
    while ( pos < len )
    {
        char c = ch[pos];
        if ( c == ',' ) commaCounter++;
        else if ( c == '"' )
        {
            pos++;
            while ( pos < len && ch[pos] != '"' ) pos++; // skip everything until the end of the string (or line)
        }
        pos++;
    }
    return commaCounter;
}
```

Something like the above *should* work ;)